# Convert PHP curl request to Java

Tags: java, php, curl

So I have this PHP code which makes a POST request to the specified URL. The $data array acts as a filter to apply to the request (for example to display the second page and maximum 10 items for that page). By default that values are "currentPage => 1" and "itemsPerPage => 100" (I'm accessing an API).

```
<?php

$usercode = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$URL = '';

$data =
    array (
        'currentPage' => 2,
        'itemsPerPage' => 10
    );

$hash = sha1(http_build_query($data) . sha1($password));

$requestData = array(
    'code' => $usercode,
    'username' => $username,
    'data' => $data,
    'hash' => $hash);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestData));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$json_pretty = json_encode(json_decode($result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json_pretty;
```

It works exactly  as intended using PHP language, but I want to achieve the same behaviour in Java. The problem is that the filters doesn't apply (for every request the values of filters are ignored and the default values are used). I tried to make the request in the same form as in PHP, but for some reason the filters doesn't apply. This is my attempt using Apache's HttpClient:

```
public class Foo
{
    private static String httpBuildQuery(List<? extends NameValuePair> parameters) {
        return URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, "UTF-8").replace("*", "%2A");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        String usercode = "";
        final String URL = "";

        String headerValueToBeEncoded = username + ":" + password;
        String encodedHeaderValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(headerValueToBeEncoded.getBytes());

        List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currentPage", "2"));
        data.add(new BasicNameValuePair("itemsPerPage", "10"));

        String passwordHash = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(password);
        String dataQueryString = Foo.httpBuildQuery(data);
        String valueToBeHashed = dataQueryString + passwordHash;
        String hash = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(valueToBeHashed);

        List<NameValuePair> requestData = new ArrayList<>();
        requestData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", usercode));
        requestData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        requestData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data.toString()));
        requestData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", hash));

        String requestDataQueryString = Foo.httpBuildQuery(requestData);

        try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build())
        {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
            request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedHeaderValue);
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestDataQueryString));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("id"));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The values of predefined that predefined strings (username, password, etc) have been left empty here because they contain sensitive information. In the last part I have printed only the values of the id's to check if the filters have been applied, but for every request the it prints 100 id's.

Comment: can you try like this:  for(JSONObject jsonObject : jsonArray)  { System.out.println(jsonObject.get("id")); }

Comment: @Saidolim I don't think it matters if I use foreach or a normal for to iterate through the JSON.

Comment: Can you give example of response from server? Difficult to understand what you have and what you want to see.

Comment: @Saidolim I see what I want to see because I get a successful response from the server. The problem is that I don't see enough results because the filters doesn't apply. May be something with the query string.

Comment: As I understand. for hashing your data you use Replace funstin in URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, "UTF-8").replace("*", "%2A"); but in sending parameters you also use .replace("*", "%2A"); I thinks you have to use without replace in 2nd time for requestDataQueryString. You have to check, what is including on Request.

Comment: @Saidolim The problem is that in Java it doesn't create the same query string as it does in PHP.